# R freezes then unable to launch - MacOSX Sierra

Tags: r, macos, freeze

I've been having an intermittent problem running R on a new (mid-2015) MacbookPro (OSX10.12.2 - Sierra) with 16GB memory.  I have R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31) -- "Sincere Pumpking Patch" installed. The R.app GUI is 1.68 (7288). The freeze seems to happen when I have multiple windows open and am switching the editor from one R code and another.  The spinning ball appears and I have to force quit of R.  I have deleted all the .Rhistory files that I can find (and I have restarted the computer) but when I launch R again, the all the edit windows appear that were open when R froze as the does the spinning ball.  I also have tried launching R from a command line, but have the same problem.  I don't know where to begin troubleshooting this problem and would appreciate any advice. Thanks.

Comment: Brief update and further query:  I tried renaming the R scripts that were being loaded when I launched R.  The system found them under their new names which I think is strange and still froze.  Then I tried re-installing R but this did not help either.  Where does R get the information about what windows were open when it was closed?

Comment: One more thing:  I just noticed the following at the bottom of the R Console window: executing: if (exists('.First') && is.function(.First) && !identical(.First, ._RGUI_..First)) .First()